# How Fast Can Toponium Form?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, weak-interaction, mesons

I understand that [Toponium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quarkonium) is only theoretical because the T quark decays too quickly.
My question is this, would a right handed T quark live long enough to form a meson?  If not, how long would it take to change from a R to L handed quark and then decay versus form a "stable" meson?

Comment: Below the electroweak phase transition, you don't get t_R independent of (b t)_L, you just get a top quark as Dirac fermion.

Comment: Why would the B/T be different that the other quarks and leptons?

Comment: The quarks and leptons of the standard model don't differ in this regard... Just so it's clear what I'm talking about: the fundamental fermion fields are "Weyl fermions", which are fermions with definite handedness, and then one consequence of the Higgs field is that they pair off into the Dirac fermions that are observed... The left-handed Weyl fermions are weak doublets containing two flavors, the right-handed Weyl fermions are singlets... So the top quark as Dirac fermion couples t_R to (b t)_L, the bottom quark couples b_R to (b t)_L, and same for lighter quarks and leptons

Comment: In the Dirac fermions, they have left handed and right handed components to their wavefunction, but if they are massive, handedness isn't conserved, so you can't create a solely right-handed Dirac top quark and have it stay purely right-handed

Comment: It wasn't clear to me from your question whether you were talking about the standalone Weyl fermion right-handed top quark, which should only exist at ultrahigh temperatures far beyond anything outside the big bang plasma, or the right-handed mode of the Dirac fermion top quark (which consists of left handed and right handed Weyl fermion tops bound by Higgs interaction). Sorry if this is a little intricate

Comment: Maybe I'll write a proper answer summarizing all this